# MySQL query returning null

Tags: mysql

```
select sum(c.cost)
from (select x.num as x, y.num as y, max(priority) as maxpriority
      from numbers x cross join
           numbers y join
           costs c
           on x.num between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and y.num between c.y and c.y + c.deltay
      where x.num between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and
            y.num between PIXELY and PIXELY and DELTAY
      group by x.num, y.num
    ) xyp join
    costs c
    on xyp.x between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and xyp.y between c.y + c.deltay and
        xyp.maxpriority = c.priority
```

I am trying to get the "cost" of a selected area in 2d which is populated by different area sizes with different costs overlapping each other by priority. (if an area is below another area it is ignored)

This is numbers:

```
Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
     1  num int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
```

This is costs:

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  x   int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 2  y   int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 3  deltax  int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 4  deltay  int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 5  priority    int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
```

What am I missing? The code is probably riddled with errors.

Comment: You can only have two values after `BETWEEN`. So `x.num between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX` is not doing what you want.

Comment: Also the between at the end looks like it only has one argument.

Comment: what do you mean by (Advanced) in your title?

Comment: @rs.: presumably it was a thought that this query is advanced in some way

Comment: Well so far nobody was able to fix it so yes it is advanced (maybe a little too advanced for you 3)

Comment: @zerkms it would be understandable if you answered the question first and then mocked the fact that it is defined as advanced, but you are unable to answer it.

Comment: @user2288298: "but you are unable to answer it" --- there is a difference between "unable" and "don't want to bother". Well, I won't bring you round since I don't care much, think what you want to think, good luck ;-)